# How can we implement a find function in Meta's Lexical editor?

Tags: reactjs, editor, text-editor, lexicaljs, lexical-editor

How can we identify text matching a certain string in Lexical editor and highlight it similarly to how the browser's find function works?

Ideally we would do so in a way that does not affect the serialized output of the editor (because search results shouldn't update the underlying document.)

*I apologize for not including code in this question. Lexical is rather new and not widely used. The documentation is sparse and incomplete so I'm unsure how to begin with this.*

I'd be very appreciative for even a suggestion for a semi-functional approach.

#### Example of desired result:

[image]